# Ignoring comment preceded or succeed by code

Tags: java, regex

This is the pattern I have used for finding multi line comments

```
private static final Pattern MULTI_LINE = Pattern.compile("/\\*(.|[\\r\\n])*?\\*/");
```

However I want to ignore comments that are preceded or succeeded by code
like this

```
1. /* Some comment */ String val = "foo";
2. String val1 = "foo1"; /* Some comment */
```

How do I alter my regex to ignore such cases?
I do not want to replace the comment, but I want to ignore such cases as comment lines in the code as I am trying to find the number of commented lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ^ boundary matcher in combination with \s to match lines that have only whitespace between beginning of the line and the beginning of the comment. Then use $ to do the equivalent for the end of the line case.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Hi @AlexVoss  I modified my regex like this (^\\s)/\*(.|[\\r\\n])*?\*/$, is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, except (a) you need to escape the asterisks in the comment delimiters as in the code you originally posted and (b) you may want to allow whitespace at the end. You may want to experiment with the expression on https://regexr.com. Turn multi-line mode on.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final Pattern MULTI_LINE_COMMENT = Pattern.compile("((?<=([\\r\\n]))([\\s]*)|^)(/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/)([\\s]*(\\n|\\z))");
```

This solved it.